# InvokePattern.Invoke() is throwing error

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation

I am new to C#. I have to write a code to make an application run Automatically(Completely UI Automation) using C#. Below is the code I have written.

```
string file = textBox1.Text;
string plnt_name = "Testing_Kabir_Plant";
string sspe = "1CK1S01";
string srev = "0";
string spe = sspe + ", Rev:" + srev;

ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo(file);
Process.Start(pro);

Thread.Sleep(5000);
AutomationElement RestoreTool = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Form1"));
Thread.Sleep(5000);

AutomationElement selPlant = RestoreTool.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "comboBox1"));

Thread.Sleep(5000);

AutomationElementCollection ciPlants = selPlant.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsSelectionItemPatternAvailableProperty, true));

foreach (AutomationElement aeplant in ciPlants)
{
    SelectionItemPattern plant = (SelectionItemPattern)aeplant.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
    if (aeplant.Current.Name == plnt_name)
    {
        try
        {
            plant.Select();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
        }
        break;
    }
}

AutomationElement getbut = RestoreTool.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "button5"));
((InvokePattern)getbut.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();

Thread.Sleep(5000);

AutomationElement speclist = RestoreTool.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "checkedListBox1"));

AutomationElementCollection list = speclist.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsSelectionItemPatternAvailableProperty, true));
foreach (AutomationElement each in list)
{
    if (each.Current.Name == spe)
    {
        ((TogglePattern)each.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern)).Toggle();
    }
}

AutomationElement log_fol = RestoreTool.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "textBox4"));
((ValuePattern)log_fol.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).SetValue("E:" + @"\sample" + @"\sample" + @"\testing");

Thread.Sleep(2000);
AutomationElement finbut = RestoreTool.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
    , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "button1"));
((InvokePattern)finbut.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();
```

My tool asks for the exe file of the application to be executed and start the process of giving values automatically.
The problem I am facing is that the last button, "button1", when invoked is throwing an exception "Specified method is not supported". This I am not facing with "button5". I don't understand why. Please help me in solving this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is the button hidden, perhaps?

Comment: no. I checked the isenabledproperty by using this   **MessageBox.Show(finbut.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty).ToString());**  The message box shows true.

Comment: Do you mind posting a screen shot of the button in inspect I would like to see all the patterns it supports.